# How to extract data from app?

Tags: applications, file-system, file-management, data-transfer

So I want to switch pedometer apps but move over my data.

I thought I could just get the database, extract the relevant entries and inject them into the other app's database. But no.

First off adb backup does not work, files are 1-4 kB. Possibly to do with my custom ROM.
Also no relevant data in /sdcard/Android/data/com.name.
It will sync with google fit but not historical data.

I located the databases in /data/data/com.name/databases but the ones I could open had no relevant data. The ones I couldn't open (requires some password) were .workdb (no clue what that is) or .workdb-wal, these are ~90 kB so it might have the data.

The app uses google sync. I thought maybe I could get at the data there but was unable to find the backup in drive.

Any  ideas how I could get at the data and then inject it into the other app?

Comment: There's no universal way to extract & migrate data from one app to another. Without knowing the specific apps and how they work, we can't provide further helps.

Comment: If the apps don't provide an export/import functionality data migration needs very detailed knowledge on how the apps work internally.

Comment: https://sqliteforensictoolkit.com/how-not-to-examine-sqlite-wal-files

Comment: https://www.staff.hs-mittweida.de/~pawlaszc/fqlite